# State/county value to be required in woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have wordpress website which runs woocommerce. 
When the customer selects country in the check out form a list of counties come as drop down but the field is showing as not required. I also want a * to come around the label.  How can I do this ? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Apply the following [Gist](https://gist.github.com/corsonr/6129163), but change `false` to `true`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'woo_filter_state_billing', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields', 'woo_filter_state_shipping', 10, 1 );

function woo_filter_state_billing( $address_fields ) { 
    $address_fields['billing_state']['required'] = true;
    return $address_fields;
}
function woo_filter_state_shipping( $address_fields ) { 
    $address_fields['shipping_state']['required'] = true;
    return $address_fields;
}
```

I tested this, and it is working.

The other option, i.e., to use filter `woocommerce_default_address_fields` as described [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) did **NOT** work.